# Media Builder Not Found Exception while Publishing into Instagram using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

We are oftenly getting "**Media Builder Not Found**" Exception while publishing media using Instagram Graph API.Can anyone know how to fix it?

Triggered URL: 
Url1 : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<**userId**>/media?access_token=<**token**>&image_url=<**imageUrl**>
&caption=<**caption**>

Url2 : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<**userId**>/media_publish?creation_id=<**creationId**>&access_token=<**token**>

Comment: A code snippet is always useful.

Comment: hi @DawidRutkowski It's not happening always..So i hope the problem is not in code.Anyhow will share the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is tricky and sad - Facebook really has outdone itself here. The issue is that uploading to Instagram using Facebook API requires 2 types of access tokens.

- When you call /media endpoint to upload an image, a ***user access token*** must be used.
- When you use /media_publish to publish a previously created image - you must use ***page access token***

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know.  Facebook really makes it difficult to use their API just because they cant collaborate effeciently to create a more proper Docs. Theres so much to process to even get to a point where you're sure of what you're doing. I did get it to work now but i still feel like I don't know what I'm doing. But im getting closer to understanding how it works. THERE'S JUST TOO MUCH BACK AND FORTH

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, in my case, using the page token to create the media object and then using the user token to publish it, solved it.

What's strange though is that before I got the Instagram permissions approved, everything worked just by using the page token...but after I got the permissions approved it started failing and I had to use the user/page token combination to make it work.