# In Instagram Graph API, when I try to publish to Instagram, I receive error 24 subcode 2207006 and cannot publish

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

For the past 3 months I have been automating posting images to my instagram account. But today it no longer works, I assume because my access token expired. It is just publish that does not work, I can still create the object, which confuses me because the new access token works for some api calls but not all.

My endpoint params for creating an object:

```
{'caption': 'Filler caption',
'access_token': 'removed',
'image_url': https://www.smashbros.com/assets_v2/img/fighter/mega_man/main.png'}
```

The object url:
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/17841406231094676/media

I import requests for python, then do

```
data = requests.post( url, endpointParams )
```

And I get back

```
{'creation_id': '17900592242391633',
'access_token': 'removed'}

publish Url:
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/17841406231094676/media_publish

---- PUBLISHED IMAGE RESPONSE -----

Response:
{
"error": {

"message": "The requested resource does not exist",

"type": "OAuthException",

"code": 24,

"error_subcode": 2207006,

"is_transient": false,

"error_user_title": "Media Not Found",

"error_user_msg": "The media with 17,900,592,242,391,633 cannot be found.",

"fbtrace_id": "AIYNvGl2IQQp5L9G7kb9F7O"

}
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Edit: My script started working again, I believe this was an error on Facebook's end

Comment: how long did this error last for you?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need 2 different kinds of tokens. A page token to create the media object and then a user token to actually post to Instagram. I'm guessing in your case it worked at first because both tokens were valid, but with time, both expired, but only 1 of them got renewed by your system.

I've been having the same issue, where I could only upload the media object but not publish it until I used a page token to create the media object and then a fresh user token to post it. By doing this I got it to work right away.

I got that solution from here, hope it helps

[Media Builder Not Found Exception while Publishing into Instagram using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810149/media-builder-not-found-exception-while-publishing-into-instagram-using-graph-ap)